# Java reflection Method invocations yield result faster than Fields?

Tags: java, performance, reflection

I was microbenchmarking some code (please be nice) and came across this puzzle: when reading a field using reflection, invoking the getter Method is faster than reading the Field.

Simple test class:

```
private static final class Foo {
    public Foo(double val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public double getVal() { return val; }
    public final double val; // only public for demo purposes
}
```

We have two reflections:

```
Method m = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("getVal", null);
Field  f = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("val");
```

Now I call the two reflections in a loop, `invoke` on the Method, and `get` on the Field. A first run is done to warm up the VM, a second run is done with 10M iterations. **The Method invocation is consistently 30% faster, but why?** Note that getDeclaredMethod and getDeclaredField are **not** called in the loop. They are called once and executed on the same object in the loop.

I also tried some minor variations: made the field non-final, transitive, non-public, etc. All of these combinations resulted in statistically similar performance.

**Edit:** This is on WinXP, Intel Core2 Duo, Sun JavaSE build 1.6.0_16-b01, running under jUnit4 and Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My educated guess would be a difference in how getDeclaredField and getDeclaredMethod are implemented:  While each time it is called, getDeclaredField would have to check for the variable type and size, in order to return an actual object or primitive type, getDeclaredMethod would return the pointer to one and the same method, which takes care of all the rest statically.

**Edit**:

My explanation is similar: A method is contained in memory only once for each class, while each object instance can have different property values.  When you get the property value by executing a method call (still using only the method pointer), the compiler has optimized the method to access the parameter, knowing the exact class hierarchy etc., while when you get the property's value by using "get", you let reflections do the getter method's job, and there can obviously be no compiler optimization.

Comment: I have added a clarification to the question, these methods are called once, outside the loop. The loop only contains the reflection invocations.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't the memory layout of the object be the same for each instance? I would imagine this can result in an optimisation where the Field reads a specific offset from the Object address. Notice that the class is final, so subclass layouts do not interfere.

Comment: Yes, exactly: The memory layout would be the same - but when you use reflections, the compiler can't know that.  When you only have such a simple task to execute, the difference between two or three operations each already accounts for 30% more speed...  I'm afraid I don't know enough about javac to have a more detailed answer, but I think this theory justifies an educated guess. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your microbenchmark, the method invocation is faster because of optimizations made by the JVM/Hotspot with in your loop.

Change your microbenchmak:

Make a loop in which: read the value by Reflection, then increase 1 (for instance), and then assign to the same Field via Reflection. And outside the loop, make a final read and System.out.println it...

Execute the two variants (Field vs Method) and you will see that the real difference is just the opposite: Method invocations are actually 30-40% slower.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

does this also imply that`double d = Foo.getVal()` is 30% faster than `double d = Foo.val`?

Comment: No. Definitly not. And reflection is *much* slower than a simple assignment.

Comment: I hope this is not the case because I can imagine people rushing to replace their getters with exposed fields, and we all know that would be A Bad Thing.